# macOS has native UPS support; where do events get logged to?

Tags: macos, ups

I have various Apple macOS systems; all of them have an APC UPS attached, all recognize the UPS and allow shutdown parameter tweaking via obvious methods in the system preferences.

Is there a way to easily get a list of UPS events?  I've looked and looked and have never found anything, even in `/var/log/` files.

I do see this in the output of `log show` (part of 250+MB of log output):

```
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376729-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : 44 Type : 2 IV: 0) with key Is Charging
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376740-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : 45 Type : 2 IV: 1) with key Is Charging
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376749-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : d0 Type : 2 IV: 0) with key Power Source State
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376760-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : 66 Type : 1 IV: 100) with key Current Capacity
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376769-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : 68 Type : 1 IV: 6716) with key Time to Empty
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376778-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : 44 Type : 257 IV: 0) with key Is Charging
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376786-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : 45 Type : 257 IV: 1) with key Is Charging
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376794-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : d0 Type : 257 IV: 0) with key Power Source State
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376802-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 84 U : 40 Type : 257 IV: 1200) with key Set Required Voltage
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376810-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 84 U : 30 Type : 257 IV: 1350) with key Voltage
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376818-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : 66 Type : 257 IV: 100) with key Current Capacity
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376825-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : 68 Type : 257 IV: 6716) with key Time to Empty
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376844-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 84 U : 5a Type : 257 IV: 2) with key Enable Audible Alarm
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376866-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 84 U : 40 Type : 257 IV: 1200) with key Set Required Voltage
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376873-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 84 U : 30 Type : 257 IV: 1342) with key Voltage
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376901-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Skipping duplicate element (UP : 85 U : 44 Type : 257 IV: 0) with key Is Charging
2023-07-02 17:16:17.376963-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] Power Source status isACSource : No , isCharging : No , isDischarging : Yes
2023-07-02 17:16:17.377131-0700 0x13a1     Default     0x0                  787    0    ioupsd: (IOHIDLib) [com.apple.iohid:ups] dispatchEvent: {
    "Current Capacity" = 100;
    "Enable Audible Alarm" = 2;
    "Is Charging" = 0;
    "Max Capacity" = 100;
    "Power Source State" = "Battery Power";
    "Set Required Voltage" = 120;
    "Time to Empty" = 111;
    Voltage = 0;
}
2023-07-02 17:16:17.377581-0700 0x20b6f3   Default     0x0                  522    0    powerd: [com.apple.powerd:battery] Received power source(psid:5000) update from pid 787: <private>
2023-07-02 17:16:17.377777-0700 0x20b80f   Default     0x0                  522    0    powerd: [com.apple.powerd:battery] Battery time remaining posted(0x3000000008c006f) Time:111 Source:Batt
2023-07-02 17:16:17.377795-0700 0x20b80f   Default     0x0                  522    0    powerd: [com.apple.powerd:battery] Battery capacity change posted(0x80064). Capacity:100 Source:Batt
2023-07-02 17:16:17.377808-0700 0x20b80f   Default     0x0                  522    0    powerd: [com.apple.powerd:battery] Power Source change. Source:Batt
2023-07-02 17:16:17.378407-0700 0x20b6f3   Default     0x0                  522    0    powerd: PowerManagement: UPS low power warning
```

Comment: What kind of Mac do you have?  Which version of macOS?

Comment: macOS 13 in most cases.  The hardware varies (mini, studio, imac).

Comment: How long was the power event?  In my experience the power event had to be more than a few seconds.  A brief “blip” wouldn’t trigger the log, but a longer would definitely  would.

Comment: Long enough to cause the machine to shutdown.  So, I would say more than 15 minutes.  I'm sure of this, the 2 machines on UPSs both shutdown.

Comment: Try this command to search for items related specifically to the `ioupsd` process:  `log show --predicate '(subsystem="com.apple.iohid") && (processImagePath CONTAINS "ioupsd")'` .  It’ll be quite lengthy, so you might want to redirect it to a file for parsing with a text editor or similar.

Comment: There is a **lot** of output.  It does seem to be UPS related, having to do with charging, voltage, audible alarms, etc.

Comment: I saved the output to a file and found the last entry with "battery" in it.  16 minutes after the first one, when it shutdown.  Next entry is me booting yesterday.  The nature of the output is quite raw.  I was hoping for something a little higher level.

Comment: Try the same command, but add in as follows:  `log show --style compact —predicate…..`. The default is “human readable” but I think we can  accommodate!  Let me know if that works and I’ll type up an answer.

Comment: Hmm.  Didn't change the output.  I can read the man page later and play with it.  Have some meetings now.

Comment: I just don't think this method is going to be fruitful.  There is just too much output.  The answer below by @Thinkr seems better, in that the output is small and compact and gives me exactly what I want to see.  It is, btw, very much like what `apcupsd` would give, if memory serves.

Comment: I wish you the best then.